# Is it possible to sum all integers in a list? (C# console)

Tags: c#

I have a list containing user entered values. I would like all integers entered to sum together at the end and the total to be displayed. Is this possible?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace BubbleSort1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
            List<int> price= new List<int>();
        enterprice:
            Console.WriteLine("Please enter price");
            Console.WriteLine("When Finished please press '/'");
            string pricex = Console.ReadLine();

            if (pricex == "/")
            {
                goto receipt;
            }
            else
            {               
                int pricey = Convert.ToInt16(pricex);
                price.Add(pricey);
                Console.Clear();
                goto enterprice;
            }

        receipt:
            Console.Clear();
            Console.WriteLine("Your Outflows:");
            Console.WriteLine(string.Join("\n", price));
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Before anyone mentions I understand there are better methods than goto and I could probably save user entered data straight as integers and I will learn how but have just started so want to take my time with it. Many thanks ;)

Comment: Loop through the collection and add them up?

Comment: @Clutchjam007 Try LINQ Sum.

Comment: I know you addressed it already, but there isnt a reason to use `goto` ever.  Get rid of it now, don't wait

Comment: I'm assuming `goto` is used here taken verbatim from the textbook or wherever OP pulled this algorithm from. Its typical to see `goto` in algorithm pseudo. But in practice `goto` is the bad kind of four letter word, you should never use it. Instead, make a function and call that instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The other answer recommends LINQ, and that is definitely the less verbose way to do it. But I have a feeling that you're just learning, so may want to have an idea of how this actually works. Below is the an abridged version of the `Linq.Sum` source code so you can see what is happening.

```
public static int Sum(this IEnumerable<int> source)
{
    int sum = 0;
    foreach (int v in source)
    {
        sum += v;
    }
    return sum;
}
```

It loops through each item in the IEnumerable, adds them to another variable, and then returns that result.

Answer (score 3):

There is a sum function on the List object.

```
var total = price.Sum();
```

It is an extension method on System.Linq.  So, you will also need.

```
using System.Linq;
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the help. Just wondering what var saves something as. I grasp it is kind of similar to an integer?

Comment: @Clutchjam007 What `var` ends up as is determined by the expression. In this case, it resolves to an integer. If the right hand side returned a string it would be a string. I personally only use var for anonymous types and prefer to be explicit about my typing. If you're just learning I would recommend to do the same. Using `var` all throughout your code tends to cause some confusion in my experience.

Comment: Like @TheBatman said its just a variable declaration for current scope.  I could have used


    `code int total = price.Sum();`


var keeps it a little more dynamic.